# SO Unknown tag - should it be removed?

Tags: discussion, tags

It seems that there are [46 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/unknown) tagged unknown on SO.  Looking at them, I'm not sure the tag really adds anything, except maybe for the "What programming language is this" questions.  Do you think any tag removal is in order?

Comment: Maybe people could subscribe to the `unknown` tag if they are polyglots and enjoy classifying questions?

Comment: @luqui, that would work if people used it to mean "I don't know what to tag this".  But, the often seem to use it to mean "I don't know about this topic".  Well, you're asking a question on a Q+A site, so it seems funny having a tag for it.  Sort of like having an `apple` tag on AskDifferent.

Comment: From my quick peek, people are using it in a way that adds no value. +1

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Agreed, it is now burninated.

[image: tag burninated]

Answer (score 3):

Giving a quick look at the questions tagged [unknown](/questions/tagged/unknown), I noticed that some of the questions already contain that word in the title, one question uses that tag and it is asking to identify a programming language, and one uses that tag for lack of a better tag.

I could probably understand using [unknown](/questions/tagged/unknown) together [language](/questions/tagged/language), but it is definitively not a good idea to use such a tag, especially when so different questions use it.
If then the tag is the only one used for a question, that means the OPs are not able to classify their own questions. I would expect that at least a tag is easily found as SO questions are generally about a programming language, and in some cases they are relative to an operating system, or architecture. In the case a question is independent from the programming language, then there is [language-agnostic](/questions/tagged/language-agnostic).

In short, I think [unknown](/questions/tagged/unknown) should be removed.

Comment: your answer is well-written and reasonable.  However, Jeff's answer has Trogdor, so I must accept his, sorry.